# Why my (android) phonegap app works on debug mode but not on release mode?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm working in an application developed with phonegap 3.3.0 and i'm using build.phonegap.com to build the apk's. This app works with a REST server, so it uses POSTs and GETs. This app works fine in debug mode, i mean, without sign the application with the builder. But if i setup the keystore to sign my android app and then i install the "app-release.apk", the installation works fine, the start of the application works fine, but all GETs and POSTs return always 404.

For the record, i've checked the access whitelist in config.xml.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you accessing your server through https and in that case does your server have a trusted ssl certificate?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Anybody found a solution for this problem? I just ran into the same issue..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have applied the self-signed certificate? Because debug: true is being set only when the app is built with a debug certificate.